# Can the degree of an affine variety increase after intersecting with a hyperplane?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Say we have an affine variety $V \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, and suppose we intersect $V$ with a hyperplane $H$, possibly not in general position. Is it possible for the degree of $V \cap H$ to be larger than the degree of $V$?

Comment: How do you define the degree of $V$ of $V$ is not a hypersurface?

Comment: The definition I'm using is that if $V$ has dimension $d$, then the degree of $V$ is equal to the number of intersection point of $V$ with $d$ hyperplanes in general position. (Including intersections at infinity and intersection multiplicity).

Comment: you mean $n-d$ hyperplanes

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam The hyperplanes have codimension $1$, so each intersection reduces the dimension of $V$ by $1$, so we need to intersect with $d$ hyperplanes total.

Comment: oops you're right got mixed up between what is dimension and what is codimension

Comment: Answered here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428205/degree-and-dimension-of-intersection-of-projective-variety-and-hypersurface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for the degree to increase. Say $V \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ is reducible: a union of a curve of degree $d$ plus one more point that doesn't lie on the curve. Then $V$ has degree $d$. But if $H$ is any plane through that extra point, then the intersection of $V$ with $H$ has degree $d+1$: the one point, plus $d$ points of intersection with the curve.

More generally, degree only sees the highest-dimensional component of $V$, but intersection with a hyperplane can bring up lower-dimensional components, raising the degree.